# Trace of product of commutators in $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Let $A,B\in\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and define $x=\operatorname{tr}(A)$, $y=\operatorname{tr}(B)$, $z=\operatorname{tr}(AB)$. It is know that these satisfy the equation $$\operatorname{tr}([A,B])=x^2+y^2+z^2-xyz-2,$$
where the commutator $[A,B]=ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ is defined in the group setting. 
For $A,B,C,D\in\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ can one obtain a similar formula for $\operatorname{tr}([A,B][C,D])$ in terms of $x=\operatorname{tr}(A)$, $y=\operatorname{tr}(B)$, $z=\operatorname{tr}(AB)$, $r=\operatorname{tr}(C)$, $s=\operatorname{tr}(D)$, $t=\operatorname{tr}(CD)$?

Edit:
I think such an equation will also need to include the variables $u=\operatorname{tr}(AC)$, $v=\operatorname{tr}(BD)$, $w=\operatorname{tr}(AD)$, $\omega=\operatorname{tr}(BC)$ (so that its level sets are $8$ dimensional surfaces).

Comment: Is there a name to that identity? Do you have a reference? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I don't, but the original identity is called the Markov identity (or some variation of this) and can be related to the character variety of a once punctured torus.

Comment: I was unclear, but was actually referring to the original one. I cannot find anything on it by that name. Why don't we just have $\operatorname{tr}([A,B])=\operatorname{tr}(AB)-\operatorname{tr}(BA)=0$?

Comment: Yep that one, check the bottom of the wiki entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Comment: @innerproduct I was confused as well, but I guess this is $[A,B]=A B A^{-1} B^{-1}$, i.e. the commutator in the group, not the algebra

Comment: Thanks, Guest1234.
@Toffomat thanks for chiming in. Makes more sense now.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I misread the above comment. I am indeed defining $[A,B]=ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ as in the group, not the algebra.

Answer (score 3):

More of an observation:

A bit more general identity is true for $2\times 2$ matrices $A$, $B$

$$\operatorname{tr} (A B \operatorname{adj}(A)\operatorname{adj}(B))+ \operatorname{tr} (A) \operatorname{tr} (B) \operatorname{tr} (A B) - \operatorname{tr} (A B)^2 = $$
$$=\operatorname{tr} (A)^2 \det (B) + \operatorname{tr} (B)^2 \det (A) - 2\det (A) \det(B)
$$
where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#2_%C3%97_2_generic_matrix)
of the matrix $A$. If $A$ has determinant $1$, then $\operatorname{adj}(A)= A^{-1}$.

For the check with WA see [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Trace%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D%5D+Trace%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D+Trace%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D.%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D+%2B+Trace%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D.%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D.Adjugate%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D%5D.Adjugate%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D%5D-Trace%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D.%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D%5E2) and [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Trace%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D%5D%5E2%20Det%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D%20%2B%20Trace%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D%5E2%20Det%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D%5D-2%20Det%5B%7B%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%7Bz%2Ct%7D%7D%5DDet%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D). It is an equality of two biquadratic forms on a space of dimension $8$.

I suggest looking at a similar equality for $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ $\  2\times 2$ matrices where we substitute the adjugate for the inverse, and also involve determinants. Perhaps using Groebner bases would be helpful.

Could be connected with polynomial invariants of the group $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ acting on uples of $2\times 2$ matrices by conjugation.

$\bf{Added:}$ I looked up the proof of the indentity of Fricke in the book quoted by the Wikipadia article in the comments above. It is based on the following identities:

$$A^2 - \operatorname{tr}(A)\cdot A + \det (A) I_2 = 0 $$
$$A + \operatorname{adj}(A)= \operatorname{tr}(A) \cdot I_2 $$

or, if one prefers, the identities for matrices of unit determinant. Worth redoing the proof, and then seeing what can be said in other cases.